# Обновления xml файла с помощью php

Tags: php, xml, обновление

Всем доброго времени суток
Помогите советом и примерами.

В общем такая проблема.
С сайта парсером была собрана информация в xml файл конкретного формата. Этот файл доступен по ссылке на другом хостинге. Теперь возник такой вопрос нужно периодически обновлять этот файл, именно обновлять информацию о доступности товара и его цене при этом не трогая других полей в файле.

Товары связанные между собой по id. Я могу тем же парсером без проблем вытащить статус и цену но не могу придумать как обновлять эти два значения в файле.

Как я представляю себе процесс сначала спарсить с сайта id товара, его цену и наличие и переписать эти значения в файле исходя по совпадениям id

Вот у меня есть такой код:

```
<offer id="69" available="true" selling_type="u">
<url>https://nyx.in.ua/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=69</url>
<price>1376</price>
<currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
<stock_quantity>5</stock_quantity>
<categoryId>20</categoryId>
<vendor>NYX Cosmetics</vendor>
<vendorCode>S111</vendorCode>
<articul>S111</articul>
<name>Набор косметики NYX Cosmetics Winter</name>
</offer>
```

С помощью парсера я получил например такие данные:

```
69
false
1370
```

Тогда в файле xml после работы скрипта я должен получить такие правки в товаре с id=69

```
<offer id="69" available="false" selling_type="u">
<price>1370</price>
```

Спасибо за подсказки и примеры как это можно сделать. Парсинг идет через simple html dom на вход поступает список ссылок с текстового файла

Comment: считываете файл, загружаете, например, в simpleXML, находите и изменяете данные, пишите обратно. Будет вопрос про конкретный этап, возвращаетесь сюда и спрашиваете, если не найдете в гугле. Это всё очень просто

Comment: Спасибо буду гуглить.

Comment: В сети информации навалом. Но как то не смог все собрать в один код который сделает то что мне нужно. Возможно кто-то поделится готовым кодом который может сделать эти манипуляции с файлом